# Why I can't open folders copied from Ubuntu on Windows?

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, windows, ntfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Seeing Ubuntu-made files on an NTFS partition from within Windows 7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84101/seeing-ubuntu-made-files-on-an-ntfs-partition-from-within-windows-7)

Is not possible for me to open whatever folder I COPY from Ubuntu to my Windows partition or whatever usb memory. Windows says the folder's (FOLDER inside usb memory, wich I can see on Win) location is either disconnected or doesn't exist. Can't copy, cut or delete the folder on Windows but with Ubuntu I can. This happens even if I create the folder on the ntfs disc. I have never had this problem before.
Files are openable however, but not if they are inside a folder.

Sorry If I haven't expressed myself, but this is basically the problem:
I have always copied folders containing all filetypes (video, music,etc) to flash drives, external disc drives, ntfs partitions, and I have opened and viewed them on windows with no problems. Now I can't.
Sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing  the folder  permissions  to your user name by entering

```
sudo chmod *username* /folder/filename
```

where folder and file name are the path to the folder you want to edit.

I want to edit, for example, `contacts.csv`  located on my desktop, so I use

```
sudo chmod rmaultz /home/rmaultz/Desktop/contacts.csv
```

or  to change a folder  recursively I would use

```
sudo chmod -R rmaultz  /home/rmaultz/Desktop
```